# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for div: 'str' and 'int' [line 14]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a function for a google foobar which counts the amount of a certain character in a list, it creates this error,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for div: 'str' and 'int' [line 14]
```

This is the code

```
def answer(s):
    sl2 = []
    ol = '10'
    if(len(s) != 0):
        if(len(s) > 200):
            print("That is too long")
        else:
            s = " ".join(s[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(s), 1))
            sl = s.split()
            sl_a = sl.count('a')
            sl_b = sl.count('b')
            sl_c = sl.count('c')
            smallest_int = min(sl_a, sl_b, sl_c)
            final_amount = ol / smallest_int #line 14 (the problem)
            print(final_amount)

answer(raw_input('Describe the M&Ms'))
```

I don't know if this is just the google foobar compiler or my limited python knowledge.

Comment: Try change line 3 to o1 = 10 without '', you are dividing string '10' to integer smallest_int

Comment: Beware with `/` operator that behaves differently with Python2 and Python3.  3/2=1 with Python2 and 3/2=1.5 with Python3

Comment: Why don't you count directly characters in the input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to divide str type value by int type value. Convert `ol` to int type before using it in division operation or set ol to `10` rather than `'10'`.

```
def answer(s):
    sl2 = []
    ol = 10
    if(len(s) != 0):
        if(len(s) > 200):
            print("That is too long")
        else:
            s = " ".join(s[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(s), 1))
            sl = s.split()
            sl_a = sl.count('a')
            sl_b = sl.count('b')
            sl_c = sl.count('c')
            smallest_int = min(sl_a, sl_b, sl_c)
            final_amount = ol / smallest_int #line 14 (the problem)
            print(final_amount)

answer(raw_input('Describe the M&Ms'))
```

`NOTE :-` By the way, in javascript, this thing works, javascript will implicitly convert '10' to 10 before using it with division operation. But, python will not allow you that.

Comment: Also worthwhile mentioning whole division vs float division, i.e. python 2 vs. python 3, as Guillaume Jacquenot pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to you are trying to divide a string against integer.
Use int to convert o1 from string to int

```
final_amount = int(ol) / smallest_int
```